# How to know the number of projects present in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

How can we know the number of projects present in a specific workspace, in eclipse IDE?

I happened to open one of the workspace which I used to work on before, and found a lot of projects in it and that's what forced me to ask this question.

Comment: Do you want to get it through some programming ? Why not just count in project perspective ?

Comment: I have a lot of projects and would like to know if there are any ways of knowing the count without counting. Am not talking about a scenario where we can count

Comment: Would love a solution or a comment, rather than a down vote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe go to the workspace folder and let your OS show the info.

A way to do this would be to use a terminal/prompt:

On Windows you could use `dir`. It will print a summary stating the number of files and directories at the bottom of the list. On Linux you can use `ls -l | grep '^d' | wc -l`.

But this list also contains `.` and `..` and maybe there are some other folders in that directory that are not projects (I have a `servers` folder for my configured application servers). But if you don't need this number to be accurate, i.e. you are just curious, than this might be enough for you

Comment: On my machine (OSX) 'ls -l' does not show . or .. (does it on your linux?). So 'ls -l | wc -l' in the workspace folder gives the number of projects.

Comment: Oh no it doesn't. That was just for windows... But if you just use `wc -l` you will also count files in that directory.

Comment: Just found another solution: `find . \( ! -name . -prune \) -type d | wc -l`. This makes a non-recursive find in the current directory that will print only directory names - and then count it

Comment: Ok, then your linux behaves the way I expected. My workspace folder has only subfolders but you are right.

Answer (score 4):

Eclipse project settings are written in .settings folder and in files .project. So you can count .settings folders or .project files.
But pay attention that in Eclipse there are nested projects! Hope it helps.